# POST/PUT json issues with Rails and PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, post, heroku

I have a heroku application running Rails and a PostgreSQL database.

My understanding is that with my current settings I am capable of posting or putting data to the appropriate pages. I am using mozilla firefox's POSTER add on to help with the testing/process at this point just for validation.

The issue though is, when I make a POST or PUT request to the appropriate page, I get a `422` error and it says `unprocessable entity`.

Here is the json I am trying to post:

```
{
    "userID":1,
    "username":"test",
    "phoneCred":1,
    "won":1,
    "lost":1,
    "previousGamePlace":1,
    "leagueID":0,
    "rosterID":0
    };
```

I believe it to be valid json, and each one of the above fields exists in my database, however when I post to the correct url, I get that 422 error. Does anyone know how to use the this feature of Rails?

the url is of this form: /users.json

Comment: what does heroku logs says. i guess you also have to send `X-CSRF-Token header` . please include it in question.

Comment: if my above comment fixes your problem i will add it in answer

Answer (score 1):

it is not valid . `rosterID` should be quoted.

Comment: Yes, I made a typo as I posted that. it's updated correctly now. The same problem persists

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error, or the record exists. Is there a way for you to check the response, may be use Curl, or debug in a browser dev tools